# Como exportar um Datatable para o Excel sem que ele formate as informações?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Preciso exportar um número para o Excel, mas ele sempre formata de uma maneira inadequada.

Forma esperada: `-8,0902322222234`

Recebida: `-809.023.222.222.234`

Os dados das colunas do `Datatable` estão tipados com string. Os dados são exibidos em um `DatagridView`.

Antes de serem exportados, eles aparecem da forma esperada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prefixe os dados com uma aspa simples  `'` na exportação.

Para o Excel, um dado prefixado por `'` é interpretado como texto, e não será formatado nem interpretado.

A aspa simples, quando no 1º caractere, não aparece no display.

**Importante:**

Sendo *strings*, os dados numéricos não serão mais alinhados à direita por padrão em línguas LTR, tampouco as datas e porcentagens funcionarão como tal.