# Mostrar string no excel sem mostrar aspa simples

Tags: c#

Tenho uma rotina que gera um excel. Tem um campo no BD(Oracle) que é varchar. Isso significa que no banco ele é formatado com zeros à esquerda. Bem, o que acontece é que quando ele é carregado no excel, o excel ignora os zeros à esquerda e mostra apenas o valor numérico absoluto. Na montagem para exibir no excel, eu tentei incluir uma aspa simples, mas quando abre no excel, a aspa também aparece, tipo assim: `'0000023654'` e não assim `0000023654`. Essse é o código que exporta para o excel:
.....

```
foreach (var item in listaItensMatMed)
                {
                    StringBuilder itens = new StringBuilder();
                    itens.Append(item.DataInclusao + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.TipoTabela + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.Tabela + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.Codigo + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.TUSS + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.Descricao + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.Fabricante + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.ReferenciaFabricante + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.RegistroAnvisa + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.ClassificacaoSimpro + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.GrupoMatMed + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.GrupoEstatistico + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.AutorizacaoPrevisa + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.UltimaVigencia + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.Valor + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.PrestadorTabelaPropria + ";");

                    Response.Write(itens.ToString());

                    Response.Write("\r");
                    //Response.Flush();
                }
.....
```

Comment: Tem certeza que isto gera alguma coisa ligado ao Excel? Não está parecendo, o problema pode ser este. Talvez com mais contexto dê para saber o que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Foi resolvido usando um "\t", assim: `itens.Append( "\t" + item.Codigo + ";");`. Isso resolveu o problema.

Comment: @pnet, o acontece se na sua descrição possuir um ponto-e-virgula ou uma aspa? para evitar este tipo de comportamento inesperado, te aconselho a usar alguma solução mais madura, como o [FileHelpers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/) ou o [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)

Comment: @TobyMosque, legal Toby. Vou dar uma olhada, mas acontece que essa solução que eu coloquei, tenho que enviar hoje ainda. Vou dar uma estudada nesses exemplos e sugerir depois uma melhoria.

Comment: Respondendo ao colega @bigown, eu acho que o comportamento do excel gera isso mesmo, pois mesmo, que você coloca qualquer "numero" com zeros à esquerda, ele não printa os zeros, a menos que ele entenda ser uma string.

Comment: Eu já respondi isso aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106395/como-exportar-um-datatable-para-o-excel-sem-que-ele-formate-as-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es

Answer (score 0):

Tente enviar o apóstrofo simples no início da string.

[image: Exemplo]